# Merge gives me much more rows in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Update: Like mentioned in the comments, my indices weren't unique. worked around via a pivot.table

I got the following code to perform a clustering on a df. This df is approximately 80 K rows (df  is named 'Kmeans'). I then have another df with a common value with 'Kmeans' (namely 'SKU_NR') with slightly less than 80K rows (this df is named 'Historie'). I want to merge df 'Kmeans' with df 'Historie', but when I do this, it gives me over 2M rows. I've done this before and then it worked. What's going wrong in the code?

```
#load in libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

 #Load and prepare data
 Historie = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

 Kmeans = Historie[['SKU_NR','ORDER_ADV_CONS_UNITS_WK_PICK']]

 Kmeans = Kmeans.dropna()

 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
 km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
 km.fit(Kmeans)
 km.predict(Kmeans)
 labels = km.labels_
 Kmeans["Classification"] = labels
 Kmeans = Kmeans[["SKU_NR","Classification"]]

 Historie 
 =Historie[['SKU_NR','WEEKNR','ORDER_ADV_CONS_UNITS_WK_PICK',
 'FORECAST_NEC_STOCK_BASE']]
 Historie = Historie.merge(Kmeans, on = "SKU_NR")
```

Comment: Your indices are probably not unique. You could try `pd.merge(Historie, Kmeans, on='SKU_NR', how='left')`

Comment: The tip is useful...But I keep getting the same problem with your solution. Any other thoughts? Maybe making a pivot table first?